# What does it mean when an iMessage doesn't say "Delivered" nor "Not Delivered"?

Tags: messages

I sent an iMessage to a friend, and at the bottom it doesn't say "Delivered" as it usually does. It doesn't say "Not Delivered" either, it just doesn't say anything at all.

What does it mean when an iMessage doesn't say "Delivered" nor "Not Delivered"?

Comment: I have the same problem it's not sending to one person I don't know why

Comment: It could mean that the reciever has turned off "Send Read Receipts", at least that's a setting on iOS 9.3.5.

Answer (score 15):

The receiving device is probably off, in sleep mode, out of cell reception, flat battery - something like that.

Answer (score 5):

I believe "Not Delivered" implies an error of some kind, whereas if nothing is displayed that just means the message is queued up to an inactive phone, or backed-up in transit over the network.

Answer (score 3):

It can mean a few things;

- The recipients' phone battery is low/dead
- The recipients' phone is out of wifi range.
- The recipient has you on block
- The recipients' phone is off

Answer (score 0):

It can mean you have been blocked. I attempted this with my number. I blocked my number send a text, didn't receive it and it never said delivered. I unblocked my number, sent text and it worked as it should by putting delivered under text and me receiving the text.

Comment: What others said was incorrect. Even if you are blocked by another phone, your messages will still say delivered. Blocking a person gives them no clue as to whether or not they are blocked. It will say delivered and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

It can also mean that the other individual has simply logged out of their account

Answer (score -1):

My friend and I tested it and when someone has their phone off it will not report "delivered" or "not delivered" until the phone is turned on. I hope that helps because I was having the same problem

Answer (score -3):

When It says “delivered” that means it has sent to your recipient and when it doesn't say delivered that means that either you don’t have  WiFi or their battery is dead so the message hasn't gone through I think.

Answer (score -3):

It could mean that they are in area with no cellular service, or they could have blocked you –accidentally or otherwise, or their phone might be flat or off.
I texted my friend and it didn't send; it never said delivered but when I text some other friends it sends.

Answer (score -3):

If it doesn't say "delivered" within an hour or 2- u were blocked. No one is texting straight thru 2 hours or on the phone more than 2 hours. And I know personally that if I get text while on phone it still says delivered. Some peeps have there's said to "read" n others don't but "delivered" is blocked if never shows up. U can call n won't go straight vm but iMessage/text message will always confirm delivery

Answer (score -4):

From my understanding, when your message says delivered under it then the person received it.  If the word "delivered" dont show it means they are on the phone and it will say delivered once they hang up.

Answer (score -5):

It means that the message was not sent to their phone.

To resolve try the following

1. in-activate the app
2. turn your phone off
3. turn wifi off then on
4. If none of this works contact your mobile provider or Apple

Answer (score -7):

When it doesn't say Delivered, it means the other person is texting someone else or on the phone.  Once they stop texting or hang up the phone, you will see the text message has been delivered.