# iMessage doesn't say "delivered"

Tags: messages

I have an internet friend, we were chatting using imessage, everything works properly until i try to send a message and then imessage doesn't say delivered neither sending. I tried using my other email address to text him, and it works, it says delivered, i know this is weird so i tried again using my first email, but it still doesn't say delivered. Did my friend blocked me?

*i don't have his number, just his email.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend turned off *iMessage* or turned off *Read Receipts*, then you won't get the *Read* notification.  If they're using a beta of iOS 10, they can turn off *Read Receipts* for individual contacts.

Also, as you suggested, if the friend decided to block you, you won't see the notifications, either.

**EDIT**: As indicated in the comments, you will see the *Delivered* notification even if *Read Receipts* has been turned off.  Edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: The "Delivered" notifications appear whether Read Receipts are on or off (see also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59297).